# Python Using numpy.linalg.norm() to Find Distance Matrix --> How Calculated?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, distance

I have a vector below called *vector*:

```
[0.465344 0.519904]
```

I also have the following matrix called *matrix_b*:

```
[[-0.701366  0.261183]
 [-0.295642 -1.41441 ]]
```

I use the following code to calculate the distance matrix.

```
dist_matrix = np.linalg.norm(vector - matrix_b, ord=2, axis=1)
```

I then print out *dist_matrix* to see the output which is:

```
print (dist_matrix )

[1.19505179 2.07862222]
```

I don't understand how mathematically the norm distance (i.e. dist_matrix) was calculated from the inputs.  Can someone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> vector = np.array([0.465344, 0.519904])
>>> matrix_b = np.array([[-0.701366,  0.261183],[-0.295642, -1.41441 ]])
>>> vector - matrix_b
array([[1.16671 , 0.258721],
       [0.760986, 1.934314]])
```

For subtraction, `vector` is broadcasted to the shape of `matrix_b`. The elements of the result are thus

```
vector[0] - matrix_b[0,0]    vector[1] - matrix_b[0,1]
vector[0] - matrix_b[1,0]    vector[1] - matrix_b[1,1]
```

Then,

```
>>> dist_matrix = np.linalg.norm(vector - matrix_b, ord=2, axis=1)
>>> dist_matrix
array([1.19505179, 2.07862222])
```

Referring to the documentation of [`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), you can see that the `axis` argument specifies the axis for computing vector norms. So here, `axis=1` means that the vector norm would be computed per row in the matrix.

Then, `ord=2` for vector norms means that for a vector `x`, the result is `sum(abs(x)**2)**(1./2)` (which is also the formula for the Euclidean distance).

So, we have, mathematically:

```
dist_matrix[0] == (abs(vector[0] - matrix_b[0,0])**2 + abs(vector[1] - matrix_b[0,1])**2)**(1./2)
dist_matrix[1] == (abs(vector[0] - matrix_b[1,0])**2 + abs(vector[1] - matrix_b[1,1])**2)**(1./2)
```